# Why am I getting a 403 error with this route?

Tags: theming, 8, users, routes

I'd like to apply the admin (or other) theme to user `/user/login` page. Since [ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) isn't available I'm attempting to implement via routes. "View admin theme" permission is granted to anonymous.

Using this route:

`my_module_name.user_login:
  path: '/user/login'
  options:
    _custom_theme: 'my_custom_theme'`

gives the correct theme, but a 403 response on the `/user/login` page. Why am I getting a 403 response (with the anticipated theme) instead of the standard login page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you don't have any access checks.

If anyone is allowed to access it, you must specify so explicitly with `_access: 'true'` in an access section.

Comment: Thanks. That's correct, though it begs the question: why DOES this work without specifying `_access`: 

`my_module.dogtracks_export_time:
  path: '/my-custom-path'
  options:
    _custom_theme: 'my_theme'`

It's also worth noting that simply adding `_access' to my use case changes the 403 to a 404. Adding `_form: ...\UserLoginForm` is required to get it working correctly.

Comment: I would think you have to do a route alter (https://www.drupal.org/node/2187643)  instead of redeclaring an existing route. @Berdir, am I just wrong?

Comment: I didn't see that you use an existing path. Yes, you should in that case.